# Exception when serializing polymorphic c# class with method hiding to json, ASP.NET core API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

To get deep into the problem, here is a console app :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(
            new PolyMorphicClass { Data = new SomeData { N = 2} }));
    }
    class BaseClass
    {
        public virtual object Data { get; set; }
    }
    class PolyMorphicClass : BaseClass
    {
        public new SomeData Data { get; set; }
    }
    class SomeData
    {
        public int N { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This code throw an invalid operation exception with this message :

> The JSON property name for 'ConsoleApp_for_test.Program+PolyMorphicClass.Data' collides with another property.

I found that if I initializing *BaseClass* instead, like below, it works

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(
           new BaseClass { Data = new SomeData { N = 2} }));
}
```

**My actual problem is:** in a WebAPI where *PolymorphicClass* is the response type of a controller action that is being serialized to json, and this same exception happens.

extra note: In the API I use this polymorphic behavior to make the response consistent across endpoints i.e. similar data type.

**My questions are :** is it ok to use the *BaseClass* instead of the *polymorphicClass* like I said above in the context of initializing API response? Is there other solutions to serialize this? Can someone explain why the exception is happening?

Comment: To clarify, After I got the answer, I realized that the correct approach is use generics and not polymorphism

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the return type with the `new` keyword, all it does is hide it and requires the use of the same signature.

You could fix this in a couple of ways.

## Using Generics

Replacing `object` with a generic type would allow for you to define `PolyMorphicClass` with a specific type for `Data`, which I believe is similar to what you're trying to do here.

```
class BaseClass<T>
{
    public virtual T Data { get; set; }
}

class PolyMorphicClass : BaseClass<SomeData>
{

}
```

## Provide implementations for the property

Properties are essentially 2 methods (a getter and a setter) and you use some default ones with `{ get; set; }`. These defaults get and set, respectively, a private member underneath the hood.

`virtual` properties are basically saying "You should override my getter and setter". Just specify an underlying member with the type `SomeData` to get and set. Here's a basic example.

```
class BaseClass
{
    public virtual object Data { get; set; }
}
class PolyMorphicClass : BaseClass
{
    private SomeData data { get; set; }

    public override object Data
    {
        get
        {
            return data;
        }
        set
        {
            data = (SomeData) value;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if you deserialize some JSON that can't be casted to `SomeData` you'll run into a runtime exception of `System.InvalidCastException`, so you may want to add some additional type checking in your setter.